# Heroku NodeJS App Build Failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, npm

I'm receiving a build failed error while deploying my NodeJS app to Heroku. Here is the build log:

---

> -----> Node.js app detected
>   -----> Creating runtime environment
>
> ```
>    NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
>    NODE_VERBOSE=false
>    NODE_ENV=production
>    NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
> ```
>
> -----> Installing binaries
>          engines.node (package.json):  8.10.0
>          engines.npm (package.json):   5.7.1
>
> ```
>    Resolving node version 8.10.0...
>    Downloading and installing node 8.10.0...
>    Bootstrapping npm 5.7.1 (replacing 5.6.0)...
>    npm 5.7.1 installed
> ```
>
> -----> Restoring cache
>          Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
>          - node_modules
>          - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
>   -----> Building dependencies
>          Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
>          npm ERR! path /tmp/build_39ba38c4a10780e26942fa5ee7294cd5/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/abbrev
>          npm ERR! code ENOENT
>          npm ERR! errno -2
>          npm ERR! syscall rename
>          npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/tmp/build_39ba38c4a10780e26942fa5ee7294cd5/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/abbrev'
>   -> '/tmp/build_39ba38c4a10780e26942fa5ee7294cd5/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.abbrev.DELETE'
>          npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>          npm ERR! enoent
>
> ```
>    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>    npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.X6IAU/_logs/2018-03-24T03_18_22_202Z-debug.log
> ```
>
> -----> Build failed
>
> ```
>    We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
>    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
>
>    If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
>    https://help.heroku.com/
>
>    Love,
>    Heroku
>      !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.  !     Push failed
> ```

---

I have deleted my node_modules folder and ran npm install and deleted/installed the abbrev npm package. Still the same error after this.

Here is my package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon bin/dev",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist",
    "build": "npm run clean && mkdir dist && babel server -s -d dist",
    "production": "npm run build && nodemon bin/production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.6.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "boom": "^7.2.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.2",
    "cron": "^1.3.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-rate-limit": "^2.11.0",
    "express-validator": "^3.2.1",
    "flat": "^4.0.0",
    "generate-password": "^1.4.0",
    "helmet": "^3.12.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.4.3",
    "moment": "^2.21.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.14",
    "mongoose": "^4.13.12",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.2",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-jwt": "^2.2.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "sendgrid": "^5.2.3",
    "twilio": "^3.13.1",
    "uuid": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.10.0",
    "npm": "5.7.1"
  }
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you could look at the bottom of this :: https://coderwall.com/p/jjcpra/clean-heroku-npm-cache   and try to flush your heroku cache an then push

Comment: @RobertRowntree that worked! Thank you!